# MySql incrementing field with value 0 (zero)

Tags: php, mysql

Hy,

I have a problem when I try to increment one field from a column of type `int(11)` which has the value 0 (zero).

Here is the query : `UPDATE Cars SET Number = Number+1 WHERE CarID='$carID'`

The problem is that if the value of Number is zero the result of increment is 2. For any other values the increment works fine.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

**Later edit:** The problem is not with the mysql query. I guess I have a bug in code. I create the pages dynamically (everything goes through index.php file and I use require_once for include files) and the problem appears only when I access the page for the first time or I make a `CTRL + F5` refresh. I also have some Rewrite rules in `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteRule ^cars/([0-9]+)/([^\n]+)\.html index.php?page=cars&carID=$1&title=$2 [NC,B,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=cars&carID=([0-9]+)&title=([^\n]+)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.cars.com/cars/%1/%2.html? [R=301,NC,L]
```

Any ideas about that?

Comment: The error is not in the MySQL query you have given. Do you have some more information?

Comment: Are you sure that you're not accidently executing the query twice? I find it highly unlikely that incremeting zero yields two.

Comment: Try it again for some more rows. Use the `mysql` command-line tool or phpMyAdmin and run your query there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like very common noobish rewrite problem.

Most people set up their rewrite *to make index.php act as a 404 handler.*

So, if there is some missed request, it's being redirected to index. and now let's talk of favicon.ico...

To solve that issue you have to dramatically LIMIT index.php activity. It should always check for the right parameters and issue 404 otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks fine, as Reiner Gereck said, there is a good chance that your code is executing the query more than once in some cases.

You could check this with some simple debugging:

Every time you execute this query, echo something, like `echo "I'm incrementing $carID"<br/>`.

Then do whatever action is required for this code to run, and count the number of times this appears. If it appears more often than you expect, you've got a bug.